# Getting the location of execution of a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is responsible for writing a log file. I would like to write a log file relative to the location of my WCF service. This service does NOT have an HttpContext available. Because of this, I cannot use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath.

How can I get the location of where my WCF service is running so that I can create a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) property of the [HostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) Class?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Environment.CurrentDirectory
```